# how to calculate the byte sum of struct in swift

Tags: swift, pointers, struct, byte

this is the code in OC

It is not easy for me to convert it to swift, especially the calculate of check sum part

If anyone knows how to write, please let me know. Thank you.

OC Code:

```
MessageToOnboard {
unsigned char header[2];
 ushort length;
 uint8_t msgID;
 uint missionID;
 ushort wayPointID;
 double lon;
 double lat;
 float height;
 unsigned char wayPointAction;
//     unsigned long reserve;
 unsigned char checkSum;

}

MessageToOnboard message;
message.header[0] = 'Q';
message.header[1] = 'Z';
message.msgID = 0x21;
message.missionID = 12;
message.wayPointID = 10;
message.lon = 34.2323242;
message.lat = 68.2121221;
message.height = 30;
message.wayPointAction = '2';
message.length = sizeof(message) -5;

uint8_t *msgBIn = (uint8_t *)&message;
int iLength = sizeof(message);
uint8_t icheckSum = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < iLength - 3; i++)
{
    icheckSum += *(msgBIn+2+i);
}

message.checkSum = icheckSum;

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(message)];
```

Swift Code:
I tried this, but it is not right, I don't know how to use pointer to calculate the sum bytes of struct in swift

```
let msgBIn = withUnsafePointer(to: &message) {$0}
print(msgBIn.pointee)
let iLength: Int = MemoryLayout<MessageToOnboard>.size
let icheckSum: UInt8 = 0
for i in 0..<iLength - 1 {

  let pointer = msgBIn.advanced(by: 2 + i)
  icheckSum += UInt8(pointer)
}
```

Comment: This is a really bad way of doing a checksum. It's dependant upon the implmentation details of the compiler, and how it chooses to lay out the memory. Generate a checksum using the fields directly, instead.

Answer (score 0):

finally, solved this problem

Message is a Struct

```
func sumByte(msg: inout Message) -> UInt8 {

    let pointer = withUnsafePointer(to: msg) {UnsafeRawPointer($0)}
    var sum: UInt8 = 0;
    for i in 0..<(MemoryLayout<Message>.size) {
        let nextP = pointer.advanced(by: i)
        sum += nextP.load(as: UInt8.self)
    }

    return sum;
}
```